# How to add image (logo) besides Button in botframework

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

On the Botframework documentation I can see that `CardAction` class has method called `Image()` which reads

> For buttons an image to include next to the buttons label. Not
>   supported by all channels.

[-Botframework SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.cardaction?view=botbuilder-3.8)

When I try to implement this I get following error in emulator:

> Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined

This is my code:

```
Buttons = new List<CardAction>
{
    new CardAction()
    {
        image= "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/11/a1/9f/11a19f51bdd6769b11e7843a15400239.jpg",
        type = actiontypes.showimage,
        title = "age rating",                                                                       
    }
}
```

There is no compiler error or anything. I don't see any image besides my button. When I click the button, the emulator shows the "undefined" error.

Is it even possible to display a logo besides image? If not, can I display more than two images of different size/shape in one hero card?

Comment: The error is quite clear, there is a parameter called url that you must define :)

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder?

Comment: @NilsW I'm using .NET

Comment: @KeithM, my bad! I should have mentioned it on my question, that according to documentation there are only 4 fields that card Action takes: type, value, title and Image. If I try to put in url as parameter, it's compilation error.

Comment: Is the error giving you a line number? Without looking at the docs my guess is there might be more fields depending on the type you choose

Comment: FYI - The documentation you linked to is the Node SDK docs.

Comment: @KeithM Nope, the error is only shown on emulator, the program does not crashes. Sadly, emulator does not give line number.

Comment: For CardActions in .NET SDK, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments

Comment: "Hero Card" is a template for a specific card layout.  If you want more layout customization options, I recommend you take a look at the [Adaptive Cards](http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/) spec.

Comment: After looking over the docs I don't see any mention of a url field either. You may want to do some debugging to see if the error is in another part of your code

Comment: @NilsW thanks for pointing that out, I could not find enough info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments , so did a google search for more extensive documentation. Did not realize it was for Node SDK. Is there the equivalent documentation for .NET besides that brief tutorial?

Comment: @NilsW I'll look into Adaptive Cards as well ! Thanks.

Comment: @user5731434 it sounds like you are looking to customize the layout of a card? The "Hero Card" is not designed to be customized like that.  You will need to design the custom card layout using the Adaptive Cards JSON spec. https://adaptivecards.io

Comment: @NilsW I found the equivalent documentation in .NET as well! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.cardaction?view=botbuilder-3.8                  Description of image property reads:  
URL Picture which will appear on the button, next to text label.

Comment: If you think you found a bug, then post it on GitHub so we can track it: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new